# Sorting a text file via Java

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I have a program that accepts multiple arguments. The first argument is the name of a text file, then after that they are just random strings.

The text file contains data in this format:

```
Blue : Chrome Outlook
Red  : Spotify Word
```

So if the program receives the argument Blue, the program will return Chrome and Outlook.

I am struggling to find a way to get the program to scan each line and store it in such a way that for example Chrome and Outlook are still linked to Blue.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the signature of the method you are writing ? It's not clear to me what you should return for `method(file, "Blue", "Red", "Grey")`

Comment: Looks like some kind of property file with : instead of = to me. How large are these file? Okay to have them in memory?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for how to parse text in java and how to make a dictionary. I suggest you start there.

Comment: Your tags suggest that you're already looking at `Map`s and `List`s, which are appropriate data structures for what you're trying to do.  SO is not a tutorial or code-writing service.  Do you have a specific problem?

Comment: I have tried using a list, however I am unsure how to return the corresponding values if I find a match in the list. I am also unsure about a Map as I can only store one value with each key so might not work here

Comment: a Map<String, List<String>> or Guava's Multimap will work for your problem

Comment: I would probably create a decorator Class, override compareTo(), and throw that in a list. You have more customization and it's a little more dynamic if the problem set ever changes. If that's too complicated for your needs then I would do as others suggested and do a little more research on data structures, or post a more specific question, while also giving us code that you have tried already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to associate a key to multiple values if you use a `Map` that stores a `Collection` of values. If you allow duplicates for your values corresponding to a key, then you may use:

```
Map<String, List<String>> dictionary = HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

You can then add elements this way:

```
public void add(String key, String value) {
    if (dictionary.containsKey(key)) {
        dictionary.get(key).add(value);
    } else {
        List<String> valueList = new ArrayList<String>();
        valueList.add(value);
        dictionary.put(key, valueList);
    }
}
```

Note: Guava's [Multimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) supports the aforementioned functionality as well.